# Como enviar datos desde una segunda actividad la primera

Tags: android

Necesito ayuda, tengo la siguiente parte del código:

```
 public void BotonAceptar (View vista){
        Intent intent= new Intent (DadesPersonals.this, EAC1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Pues bien había pensado en hacer algo así:

```
 Adreça = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.Adreça );
 Adreça.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 String adreça=Adreça.getText().toString();
```

Pero me da error.

El programa tiene que hacer lo siguiente:

Tiene que volver a la Clase EAC1 y mostrarme la pantalla hasta aquí bien, pero justo hay un botón el de Adreça que esta oculto y necesito que se muestre.

Para explicar un poco más el funcionamiento:
Mi programa pasa por la pantalla EAC, pongo el nombre si el programa recibe un nombre entonces desbloquea el botón Adreça, puedo editarla. Cuando le doy a editar me pasa a otra clase que se llama Dades. 
En Dades una vez introduzco el valor Adreça y le doy Aceptar me lleva a la página anterior pero claro con el valor de Adreça desbloqueado (es decir visible).

Como puedo hacerlo?
gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar el metodo `starActivityForResult`. Esto es para que cuando navegues de la segunda actividad a la primera, la primera sepa que hacer.

Por ejemplo en tu primera actividad lanzas la segunda de la siguiente manera:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(EAC.this, Adreca.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 11);
```

Como la indicamos la segunda actividad que esperamos un resultado de ella, entonces ahora, para enviar los datos de la segunda a la primera indicando que desbloquee el buton seria asi:

```
Intent resultado = new Intent(); // aqui especificamos los datos que queremos enviar la primera
resultado.putExtra("desbloquear_boton", true);
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultado);
 finish();
```

Entonces para recibir los parametros en la primera sera asi:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 11) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            boolean desbloquear=data.getBooleanExtra("desbloquear_boton", false);
            if(desbloquear) {
               // desbloquas el boton
            }

        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // la respuesta fue cancelada, no desbloquear el boton
        }
    }
}//
```

Comment: me da errores el código no se muy bien como aplicarlo.. Voy a buscar más información por google! Gracias.

Comment: En que parte te da error?

Comment: Creo que es problema mio de no saber aplicarlo 100%

Comment: Por ejemplo cuando copio la parte de:   Intent intent = new Intent(EAC.this, Adreca.class);
   starActivityForResult(intent, 11); , la parte de starActivity me sale en rojo como si tuviera que crear un método.

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta e indica donde te falla para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Es lo que te comento, no acabo de entender el código 100% y no sé donde poner X cosas.

Comment: el metodo `starActivityForResult` lo estas ejecutando en el activity principal o en otro lugar?

Comment: en el principal, dentro de OnCreate..

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66217/discussion-between-einer-and-montse-mkd).

Answer (score 1):

El problema que yo veo es es que **DadesPersonals** hereda **EAC1**.
Tienes que crear una cadena en EAC1

```
 public static final String MI_DATA = "mi_data";
```

En **oncreate()** del la clase EAC1 coloca los siguiente:

```
    try {

        String  accion = getIntent().getStringExtra(MI_DATA);

        if (accion.equals("mostrar")) {
            mostrarBotones();
        } else {
            ocultarBotones();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("Data","Error");
    }
```

Crea los metodos mostrarBotones() y ocultarBotones().
La primera vez que se cree al no existir la llamada pasara por el error.

```
private void ocultarBotones(){
    Log.v("Data","Ocultar Botones");
}

private void mostrarBotones(){
    //Aca coloque las acciones para mostrar los botones
    Log.v("Data","Mostrar Botones");
}
```

Crea los dos metodos para los botones que te arrojan error.

```
public void BotonAceptar (View vista){

    Intent intent= new Intent (getBaseContext(), EAC1.class);
    intent.putExtra(MI_DATA,"mostrar");
    startActivity(intent);

}
public void BotonCancelar (View vista){
    Intent intent= new Intent (getBaseContext(), EAC1.class);
    intent.putExtra(MI_DATA,"ocultar");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

y colocales las acciones que quieres realizar al ser presionados.

En la clase **DadesPersonals** sobrescribe los métodos de la clase padre y dejalos vacíos.

```
public void BotonAceptar (View vista){

}
public void BotonCancelar (View vista){

}
```

Esto hace que al llamar desde **DadesPersonal** a los métodos **BotonAceptar** y **BotonCancelar** desde la propiedad **onClick** de los botones ejecute las acciones pero en EAC1 ya que esta ejecutando los métodos de la clase padre.

Comment: ostras gracias, ya lo había solucionado con el compañero pero me gusta tener otra forma! :)