# Pasar a otro Activity Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
 public void BotonAceptar (View vista){
        Intent intent= new Intent (DadesPersonals.this, EAC1.class);
        startActivity(intent);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);
       EAC1 mostrar = new EAC1();
       mostrar.MostraryOcultarBotones();
```

Mi idea es cambiar al activity EAC1 y una vez cambiada la pantalla me muestre los botones ocultos que hay.

Pero me da error, ¿podéis ayudarme? ¿Que tengo que hacer?

**EDITADA:**

El flujo de patanllas es el siguiente:

Pagina EAC que con un boton pasa a la página :
DADES que en esta página hay un boton para volver a la página EAC.
Pero necesito que al volver a esta página se muestren botones ocultos..

La duda es si añado mostratBotones() en el EAC1 en el create directamente me borra la pantalla primera que es la misma pero sin botones.

Espero haberme explicado.

**Error:**

> 09-26 11:15:39.415 1586-1586/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClick‌​Listener.onClick(App‌​CompatViewInflater.j‌​ava:293)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)

Comment: ¿Que error te marca?

Comment: Si cambias de activity deberias poner la función de mostrar botones ocultos en el create de EAC1

Comment: El problema que tengo es que necesito que se muetren solo al darle al boton Aceptar. No antes.. 

Es decir tengo una página previa que si hago lo que me comentas la pierdo.. T_T

Comment: error el siguiente: 09-26 11:15:39.415 1586-1586/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
       ..................

Comment: Si no he entendido mal, vas desde una actividad a otra y al volver tienes que tener ciertos botones ocultos, ¿no es así? ¿Porqué no lanzas la segunda actividad con startActivityForResult y al volver a la primera actividad ocultas los botones?

Comment: Eso estaba pensando ahora @PabloSimonDiEstefano pero no me ha quedado claro si vuelve a la primera (EAC) o a la que se va es otra (EAC1), porque como tu dices si vuelve a la primera con el startActivityForResult se podría resolver

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano    a ver si me explico.
Primero se abre EAC SIN BOTONEs, paso a DADES, de dades tengo que ir a EAC pero mostrando botones que hay dentro ocultos.

Comment: @JOACER se me entiende? xD Es que es un poco raro. Pero el tema es que yo entro en EAC que solo hay un boton, pero en su interior hay muchos ocultos. en el boton del EAC paso a otro layout que se llama DADES. Dentro de este cuando apreto otro botón me regresa al EAC pero con toda su información.

Comment: Entonces tienes que lanzar la actividad DADES con startActivityForResult, mira como se hace: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=es-419

Comment: @MontseMkd perdon por no contestarte antes, he estado liado, pero como bien te indica Pablo lo puedes resolver con  el startActivityForResult, además acabo de ver que ya resolvieron tu duda en tu otra [ pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104984/14088). Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás teniendo es que se está ejecutando el código de los botones una vez llamado el `startActivity()` y por eso estás teniendo error. Ya que `startActivity ()` no termina ni cierra instantáneamente el código del que se llama, añade el intent para procesarlo posteriormente ya que es una petición, por lo que en tu caso ese código se ejecuta y te da error.

Para solventar esto yo trasladaría el código de mostrar los botones al OnCreate() de la Actividad `EAC1` quedando tu código de la siguiente forma:

**Activity Actual**

```
public void BotonAceptar (View vista){
        Intent intent= new Intent (DadesPersonals.this, EAC1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Activity EAC1**

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);
        MostraryOcultarBotones();
}
```

Comment: El problema que tengo es que necesito que se muetren solo al darle al boton Aceptar. No antes.. Es decir tengo una página previa que si hago lo que me comentas la pierdo..

Comment: Es decir ahora el enlace entre EAC1 y Dades me lo hace perfecto. Pero pierdo la pagina EAC1 sin botones. Mi ciclo de programa es:

Pagina EAC sin botones, 
enlazo a pagina DADES.
Dades enlazo a EAC pero con botones.  Es decir la página EAC botones y sin es la misma. Ese es el problema.. pero me lo ponen así en el instituto.. :(

Comment: y la función de BotonAceptar() ¿donde está ?.  Todo este flujo que estás diciendo lo podrías detallar en la pregunta ya que es un poco confuso lo que estás mencionando en los comentarios y además poner el error que estás obteniendo, sino es más complicado echarte una mano

Comment: voy edito, dame 5 minutos.